# Subsite as unique Google search result

Tags: seo

I have a question regarding SEO:
let's say I have a site example.com, and a subsite example.com/mysite.
Is it possible (with proper SEO) for "mysite" to show up in Google search results as a unique result? Right now it's under "More links from example.com domain". If this is not possible, would subdomain work (mysite.example.com)?

With regards,
Looted

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually "example.com/mysite" is look like a page of "example.com" so it is possible to show up in Google search results as a unique result.

And sub-domain like- mysite.example.com is possible to display in Google search results separately.